# Jinja can't identify model when using with Modal file

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm learning to develop using Flask. Therefore, I didn't use the standard convention directory structure but used my own structure to understand what breaks at what place and what custom configurations I need to use to fix it.

I intend to use Modals for my HTML page but after I include the modal and refresh page I get the error as follows:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'item' is undefined
```

This is my project structure:

```
project
  | - src
  |    | - run.py
  |    | - pkgs
  |         | - __init__.py
  |         | - <routes and model files>
  | - templates
         | - includes
         |      | - modals.html
         | - file.html
```

I have specified the template location for the Flask app using:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir, static_url_path='/static', static_folder=static_dir)
```

I am displaying items in the `file.html` file. When I don't use custom class for modal (eg: `<div class="modal fade" id="Modal-MoreInfo"`), everything works fine. I can see the Modal when I try to access my HTML page. But when I include custom Modal as follows, things break down:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal-MoreInfo-{{ item.idx }}"
```

Any reference to `item` in the modal file results in the above error. I have included the following line in the `file.html` page:

```
{% include 'includes/modals.html' %} <!-- At the start of the block -->

{% for item in items %}

    ... HTML table display code here ...
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-outline btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal-MoreInfo-{{ item.idx }}">More Info</button>
</td>
```

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong? (I am inclined to believe I have to set some value in the Flask app to find the `includes` directory but I'm not sure. I'm just learning and wish to know what I can fix)

Answer (score 0):

I figured the error. I need to include the `include` part within the `for` loop. At the `for` loop we introduce the variable `item` and I was trying to reference it before initiation. Mistake on my part.